# How to Change Font Family for textInput Placeholder in React Native

Tags: react-native, placeholder

I have to change the font family for `textInput`'s Placeholder text.  If we add this `secureTextEntry={true}`, the mentioned font Family is set for placeholder text.

```
<TextInput style={styles.textboxfield}  secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Password" />
```

But if we remove this `secureTextEntry={true}`, we can't set font-family for placeholder

```
<TextInput style={styles.textboxfield} placeholder="Password" />
```

Style is : textboxfieldd: {
       height: 39,
       backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
       marginBottom:0,
       fontFamily:'Inconsolata-Regular',
   },

How can I change the font family for placeholder text ?

Comment: This is a React Native issue. A fix is scheduled to be released when RN 0.42 comes out. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4600) and the fix [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12000).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```js
<TextInput
    secureTextEntry={(this.state.email.length <= 0 && this.state.emailStatus != 'onFocus') ? true : false}
    style={styles.textboxfieldd}
    placeholderStyle={styles.textboxfieldd}
    onFocus={this.changeStatus.bind(this, 'emailStatus', 'onFocus', '')}
    onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
    value={this.state.email}
    placeholder={this.state.emailStatusPH}
    placeholderTextColor="#D8D8D8" />
```

> > Exactly this line => secureTextEntry={(this.state.email.length<=0 && this.state.emailStatus!='onFocus') ?true:false}   solves the problem .
> >
> > Because if we give secureTextEntry={true} means fontfamily is set to placeholder text but field changed as password , so for that only we wrote like this . secureTextEntry={(this.state.email.length<=0 && this.state.emailStatus!='onFocus') ?true:false}
> >
> > If that field length is 0 and not focused means it will set true secureTextEntry={true} so the placeholder text is set to mentioned fontfamily

Comment: not to be super nitpicky, but you dont need to return a boolean in a turnery. the it could be written as `secureTextEntry={!this.state.email.length && this.state.emailStatus !== 'onFocus'}`

Comment: the prop `placeholderStyle` seems to not be documented. It also did not work for me. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: "placeholderStyle" doesn't work for me either. This sounds like a great idea, am I missing something or has this been deprecated?

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as placeholderStyle doesn't work at least in RN 0.59. Jon Wyatt 's method of conditional styling worked for me

Answer (score 14):

The way I solved this was to conditionally style the `fontFamily` (or style) on the presence or absence of the value i.e.

```
<TextInput
  style={{ fontFamily: value ? 'OpenSans-Regular' : 'OpenSans-Italic' }}
  value={value}
  onChangeText={onChange}
/>
```

This way the font family is italic for the placeholder (when `value === ''`) and regular when text is shown.

Above is not tested as I was using styled components but concept should be the same. Also this only works if `TextInput` is rendered as a controlled component so you have access to `value`.

Answer (score 4):

Textinput can have a Text child.

So you can have

```
<TextInput>
 <Text style = {value.length == 0? styles.hint : styles.input}>
  {value.length == 0? hint : value}
 </Text>
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this by length of your password like :

```
  <TextInput
      secureTextEntry={this.state.password.length === 0? false : true}
  />
```

Comment: Or more simply, you could say `secureTextEntry={ this.state.password.length > 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the font once, you can just set `fontFamily: yourFontFamilyName`

If you plan on using your font in many place I suggest you create a class that will use the same fontFamily everyTime :

You can do it this way : (example with Quicksand as font-family)

```js
import React, {TextInput} from 'react-native';

import _ from 'lodash';

var OldTextInput = TextInput;

class NewTextInput extends OldTextInput {
  defaultProps = {};
  render() {
    var props = _.clone(this.props);

    if (_.isArray(this.props.style)){
      props.style.push({fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'});
    } else if (props.style) {
      props.style = [props.style, {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'}];
    } else {
      props.style = {fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Regular'};
    }

    this.props = props;

    return super.render();
  };
}

export default NewTextInput;
```

and then use TextInput by requiring it in every file (`import TextInput from './TextInput'`)

Comment: I have tried with " fontFamily: Inconsolata-Regular "  but unable to change Font family For PLACEHOLDER .   and i have added  style  above .

Comment: Answer is not addressing actual problem about placeholder

Answer (score 1):

You're likely experiencing this on Android with React Native <= 0.64. In which case here's a solution:

```js
<TextInput ref={ref => ref && ref.setNativeProps({ style: { fontFamily: 'FONT_NAME' } })} />
```

For more information and alternatives that might work better for you look at this [issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30123#issuecomment-815133549) on Github

Answer (score 0):

**Add fontSize={20}**

```
<TextInput style={styles.textboxfield}  secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Password" fontSize={20}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me

```
      fontWeight: 'normal',
```

good luck :)